# If $~A~$ is a $~n\times n~$ matrix in $~\mathbb R~$, $~A^3=I~$ and $~AB=-BA~$, how to prove $~\text{tr}(B)=0~$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $~A~$ is a $~n\times n~$ matrix in $~\mathbb R~$, $~A^3=I~$ and $~AB=-BA~$, how to prove $~\text{tr}(B)=0~$?

If $~A=I~$, then $~AB=B=-BA=-B \implies B=-B~$.

Then $~B~$ must be zero matrix with diagonals all zero and must have a trace of zero.

But $~A~$ does not have to equal $~I~$. Am I on the right track and where should I go from here?

Comment: Please use MathJax and reasonably standard notation.

Comment: "A is an n*n vector in R" ? Do you mean "A is a **matrix** with real entries" ?

Answer (score 5):

With

$A^3 = I \tag 1$

and

$AB = -BA, \tag 2$

we have

$B = A^3B = -A^2BA = ABA^2 = -BA^3 = -B, \tag 3$

so just as in the case $A = I$ we find that

$2B = 0 \Longrightarrow B = 0, \tag 4$

from which the result

$\text{tr}(B) = 0 \tag 5$

instantly follows.

Comment: +1: Nice. I was struggling with real Jordan forms...

Comment: @copper.hat:  sometimes the obvious works!  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

$A^3=I$ implies that $A$ is invertible. Thus $AB=-BA$ implies that $B=-A^{-1}BA$. Taking traces on both sides, we get $\operatorname{tr}(B)=-\operatorname{tr}(B)$. Hence $\operatorname{tr}(B)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$AB = -BA$

$\implies B = -A^2BA$

$\implies Tr(B) = Tr(-A^2BA)$

$\implies Tr(B) = Tr(-AA^2B)$

$\implies Tr(B) = -Tr(B)$

$\implies Tr(B) = 0$